# Getting all values of various rows which have the same value in one column with awk

Tags: loops, awk

I have a data set (`test-file.csv`) with tree columns:

```
node,contact,mail
AAAA,Peter,peter@anything.com
BBBB,Hans,hans@anything.com
CCCC,Dieter,dieter@anything.com
ABABA,Peter,peter@anything.com
CCDDA,Hans,hans@anything.com
```

I like to extend the header by the column `count` and rename `node` to `nodes`.
Furthermore all entries should be sorted after the second column (`mail`).
In the column `count` I like to get the number of occurences of the column `mail`,
in `nodes` all the entries having the same value in the column `mail` should be printed (space separated and alphabetically sorted).

This is what I try to achieve:

```
contact,mail,count,nodes
Dieter,dieter@anything,com,1,CCCC
Hans,hans@anything.com,2,BBBB CCDDA
Peter,peter@anything,com,2,AAAA ABABA
```

I have this awk-command:

```
awk -F"," '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=",";
printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n", "contact","mail","count","nodes"
}
NR>1{
    counts[$3]++;     # Increment count of lines.
    contact[$2];      # contact
}
END {
    # Iterate over all third-column values.
    for (x in counts) {
    printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n", contact[x],x,counts[x],"nodes"
    }
}
' test-file.csv | sort --field-separator="," --key=2 -n
```

However this is my result :-(
Nothing but the amount of occurences work.

```
,Dieter@anything.com,1,nodes
,hans@anything.com,2,nodes
,peter@anything.com,2,nodes
contact,mail,count,nodes
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `gnu awk`:

```sh
awk '
BEGIN {
   FS = OFS = ","
   printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n", "contact","mail","count","nodes"
}
NR > 1 {
   ++counts[$3]    # Increment count of lines.
   name[$3] = $2
   map[$3] = ($3 in map ? map[$3] " " : "") $1
}
END {
   # Iterate over all third-column values.
   PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc";
   for (k in counts)
       print name[k], k, counts[k], map[k]
}
' test-file.csv
```

**Output:**

```sh
contact,mail,count,nodes
Dieter,dieter@anything.com,1,CCCC
Hans,hans@anything.com,2,BBBB CCDDA
Peter,peter@anything.com,2,AAAA ABABA
```

Comment: How can I change `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"` to sort e.g. by column `count`?

Comment: Yes definitely. Just use `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"` in the code above.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
FNR==1{
  sub(/^[^,]*,/,"")
  $1=$1
  print $0,"count,nodes"
}
FNR>1{
  nf=$2
  mail[nf]=$NF
  NF--
  arr[nf]++
  val[nf]=(val[nf]?val[nf] " ":"")$1
}
END{
  for(i in arr){
    print i,mail[i],arr[i],val[i] | "sort -t, -k1"
  }
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                 ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }                   ##In BEGIN section setting FS, OFS as comma here.   
FNR==1{                               ##if this is first line then do following.
  sub(/^[^,]*,/,"")                   ##Substituting everything till 1st comma here with NULL in current line.
  $1=$1                               ##Reassigning 1st field to itself.
  print $0,"count,nodes"            ##Printing headers as per need to terminal.
}
FNR>1{                                ##If line is Greater than 1st line then do following.
  nf=$2                               ##Creating nf with 2nd field value here.
  mail[nf]=$NF                        ##Creating mail with nf as index and value is last field value.
  NF--                                ##Decreasing value of current number of fields by 1 here.
  arr[nf]++                           ##Creating arr with index of nf and keep increasing its value with 1 here.
  val[nf]=(val[nf]?val[nf] " ":"")$1  ##Creating val with index of nf and keep adding $1 value in it.
}
END{                                  ##Starting END block of this program from here.
  for(i in arr){                      ##Traversing through arr in here.
    print i,mail[i],arr[i],val[i] | "sort -t, -k1"  ##printing values to get expected output and sorting it also by pipe here as per requirement.
  }
}
' Input_file                          ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** In case you want to sort by 2nd and 3rd fields then try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
FNR==1{
  sub(/^[^,]*,/,"")
  $1=$1
    print $0,"count,nodes"
}
FNR>1{
  nf=$2 OFS $3
  NF--
  arr[nf]++
  val[nf]=(val[nf]?val[nf] " ":"")$1
}
END{
  for(i in arr){
    print i,arr[i],val[i] | "sort -t, -k1"
  }
}
'  Input_file
```